# Is setting batch norm not trainable during training meaningful?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, batch-normalization, object-detection-api

In tensorflow Object Detection API, in the faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py, the default setting is to make batch norm parameters not trainable during "TRAINING". The comments in the codes are as below

```
batch_norm_trainable: Whether to update batch norm parameters during
    training or not. When training with a relative large batch size
    (e.g. 8), it could be desirable to enable batch norm update.
```

In my understanding, if we do not set batch norm parameters trainable, the initial values for mean, standard deviation, and etc. will always be kept unchanged. This is OK for fine tuning, but would be problematic for training from scratch. This does not make any sense to me. Could anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: Is the question about default value in this network or in general?

Comment: I am talking about general training from scratch. If fine tuning from an existing model, the default values are meaningful. But if training from scratch, the default values are not reasonable, e.g., 0 for mean, 1 for std.

Comment: The authors say that trainable mean and variance is feasible when the batch size is relatively large. Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: That does seem reasonable. My emphasize is that when batch size is small, NOT updating mean and variance do NOT seem reasonable. I think both values should be always updated during training, no matter of the batch size.